# How to display Submit Screen only one time?

Tags: java, android

I am using this code in main activity for display Registration detail page only one time.

```
setContentView(R.layout.register_data);
startActivity(new Intent(RegisterDetail.this, MainActivity.class));

getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
if (isFirstRun){
    .edit()
    .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false)
    .apply();
}
```

but I have problem. If some one close app without submit details and reopen app, that page doesn't display.
I want to display `register_data` page until user doesn't submit details.

Comment: Save the preference on button's `onClick` then. Where are you calling it from now?

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult` - that way, only when the register activity will end, you will save the sharedPrefernces.

Comment: I'll add this as a comment since the answer was deleted.  https://github.com/jonfinerty/Once

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are shared between activities - why don;t you write the preference only when you have received confirmation that the registration details have been entered (and saved correctly on the server-side)?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `MODE_PRIVATE` to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` while creating the file and one problem is that you are calling `startActivity(...)` before checking if the `PREFERENCE.xml` file contains true or false. So first check whats is present inside the file and that accordingly take the action